# Can you animate within angular ng-view?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, animation, ng-view

I am new to Angular but I was wondering if you could animate inside ng-view once the template has been loaded?

For example, I want to click on a link within my navigation and load a html template within the ng-view, within this html template then i want individual divs to **automatically animate/fade** onto the page **without any further clicking/interaction needed by the user**.

So it all comes together as one smooth animation from that initial click on the navigation.

Is this possible? So far all the info I have seen, just talks about **animating the actual ng-view** itself and **not the html content** located dynamically.

Any help will be most appreciated!

Comment: How do you set the data for the individual divs (show us a minimal amount of code for that)

Comment: I have set up an example in Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/cDgMrkwg3TQPLzNTbo2A?p=preview Ideally the 1 & 2 divs on the web page would fade in on sequence, one after the other when the page loads.